# Pow registration view keeps displaying incorrect html file

Tags: html, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am working on a project which is a chat web application based on this article: https://curiosum.com/blog/elixir-phoenix-liveview-messenger-part-3. I have reached the part where user authorization is implemented and I have encourted a weird problem. According to the article and it's github representation everything is set up properly. There are two buttons - "sign up" and "register" leading to */session/new* and */registration/new* respectively. Their html representations are in paths *lib/chat_web/templates/pow/session/new.html.eex* and *lib/chat_web/templates/pow/registration/new.html.eex* as they should be. But when I press those buttons they keep redirecting me to the same html page which is *lib/chat_web/templates/layout/app.html.eex*. If I delete and of the new.html.eex files redirection ends up in *Could not render "new.html"* error which suggests to me that routing is correct. I really am out of ideas what my be the cause of this problem. I use following versions:

- Elixir 1.14.2
- Phoenix 1.6.15
- Pow 1.0.27

Link to branch in my repository: https://github.com/ArturMarekNowak/Chat/tree/wip/authorization

[image]

/lib/chat_web/templates/layout/app.html.eex

```
<%= if Pow.Plug.current_user(@conn) do %>
  <li><%= link "Profile", to: Routes.pow_registration_path(@conn, :edit) %></li>
  <li><%= link "Sign out", to: Routes.pow_session_path(@conn, :delete), method: :delete %></li>
<% else %>
  <li><%= link "Register", to: Routes.pow_registration_path(@conn, :new) %></li>
  <li><%= link "Sign in", to: Routes.pow_session_path(@conn, :new) %></li>
<% end %>
```

/lib/chat_web/router.ex

```
defmodule ChatWeb.Router do
  use ChatWeb, :router
  use Pow.Phoenix.Router
  import Phoenix.LiveView.Router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug(:accepts, ["html"])
    plug(:fetch_session)
    plug(:fetch_live_flash)
    plug(:protect_from_forgery)
    plug(:put_secure_browser_headers)
    plug(:put_root_layout, {ChatWeb.LayoutView, :root})
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug(:accepts, ["json"])
  end

  pipeline :protected do
    plug(Pow.Plug.RequireAuthenticated,
      error_handler: Pow.Phoenix.PlugErrorHandler
    )
  end

  scope "/" do
    pipe_through(:browser)

    pow_routes()
  end

  scope "/", ChatWeb do
    pipe_through(:browser)

    get("/", PageController, :index)
  end

  # Make conversation routes protected by requiring authentication
  scope "/", ChatWeb do
    pipe_through([:browser, :protected])

    resources("/conversations", ConversationController)

    live("/conversations/:conversation_id/users/:user_id", ConversationLive, as: :conversation)
  end
end
```

/lib/chat_web/views/pow/session_view.ex

```
defmodule ChatWeb.Pow.SessionView do
  use ChatWeb, :view
end
```

/lib/chat_web/templates/pow/session/new.html.eex

```
<h1>Register</h1>

<%= form_for @changeset, @action, [as: :user], fn f -> %>
  <%= if @changeset.action do %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <p>Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below.</p>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= label f, Pow.Ecto.Schema.user_id_field(@changeset) %>
  <%= text_input f, Pow.Ecto.Schema.user_id_field(@changeset) %>
  <%= error_tag f, Pow.Ecto.Schema.user_id_field(@changeset) %>

  <%= label f, :nickname %>
  <%= text_input f, :nickname %>
  <%= error_tag f, :nickname %>

  <%= label f, :password %>
  <%= password_input f, :password %>
  <%= error_tag f, :password %>

  <%= label f, :confirm_password %>
  <%= password_input f, :confirm_password %>
  <%= error_tag f, :confirm_password %>

  <div>
    <%= submit "Register" %>
  </div>
<% end %>


<span><%= link "Sign in", to: Routes.pow_session_path(@conn, :new) %></span>
```

Comment: What versions of [tag:elixir], [tag:phoenix-framework] do you use in the first place?

Comment: My versions are: elixir 1.14.2, phoenix 1.6.15